# Efficiently iterate over binary numbers and check the value of a bit in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, binary, bit, bit-shift

I need to iterate over the numbers from 0 to X and for each number, i, I need to check whether the bits at positions a, b, c, d, e are true or false.

Is there an easy way to do this that is efficient in Javascript? Currently I am thinking of manually iterating over the numbers, converting them to binary strings, and then doing `string[a] === "0"` or something.

Comment: you may have a look to bitwise operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this, you can use **bitwise operators**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Basically, you have your &, | and XOR operators, that you can use and combine to get the results you want.

If for example you want to check if the number 2 (10 in binary), has a a bit turned on in the 2nd index, you can use the expression
**2 & 2 > 0**. The expression will return **true**.

You want to & the number you want to check, with the number that has a bit turned on only in the index you want to check, if you want to check if index 3 has a bit turned on, use the number 4 (100 in binary) to compare against.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, k); ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
        const jthBitIsSet = (i & (1 << j)) !== 0;
        // rest of code...
    }
}
```

`k` effects the number of leading 0s. For example, if `k` = 3, then 1 becomes `001`.